# how can i add icons to drawer navigator items that have stack navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i want to add icons to drawer items which have separate stack navigation screens. When i try to add drawer Icons to navigation options inside of the main screen, nothing show. Here's a snippet of my code

```
const HomeScreenNav = createStackNavigator({
  main: {screen: Main },
  providers: { screen: Providers},
  providerProfile: { screen: ProviderProfile},
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'main',
})
```

Then my drawer navigation

```
const AppDrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
   home: { screen: HomeScreenNav },
   appointments: {screen: Appointments}
}, {
   initialRouteName: 'home',
   drawerBackgroundColor: '#fff7fc',
   contentComponent: drawerComponent,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **navigationOptions** to the routes of your drawerNavigator. This is how you one can add icons and other components like text, label, title etc and customize your navigation drawer. Here's your modified code.:

```
    const AppDrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
         home: { screen: HomeScreenNav,
                 navigationOptions: {
                 drawerIcon: (
                      <Icon name={$YourIconName} size={24}
                          ..
                          //you can also add color and other Icon props here                        
                      />
                    ),
                  },
                },
         appointments: {screen: Appointments,
                         navigationOptions: {
                         drawerIcon: (
                              <Icon name={$YourIconName} size={24}
                                  ..
                               //you can also add color and other Icon props here                        
                              />
                           ),
                         }, 
                       }
     }, {
         initialRouteName: 'home',
         drawerBackgroundColor: '#fff7fc',
         contentComponent: drawerComponent,
     })
```

Below is the code, add it inside navigationOptions on how you can add customized text to your navigation drawer:

```
    ..
    drawer: {
            label: () => <Text>My Home</Text>
          },
    ..
```

Similarly, you can specify title to your header, where you wish to change the header title on selecting corresponding option in your drawer navigator.

```
    ..
    title:"My Home"
    ..
```